# using regex in python to find strings which starts with exactly N digits?

Tags: python, regex

I should tag my strings if they start with two digits as 'basic', and the ones that start with 5 digits as 'complex'.
for example:

`11abc is 'basic'`

`12345ad is 'complex'`

`22 is'basic'`

can anyone help me with it, please?

Comment: please, send us what you tried.

Comment: i think he hasn't tried anything yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_of_string = ["1212a", "12fddfd", "22222trtyr"]
regex = r"\d+"
answer = ""
for string in list_of_string:
    number_of_digits = re.match(regex, string).group()
    if len(number_of_digits) == 5:
        answer = "complex"
    if len(number_of_digits) == 2:
        answer = "basic"
    print(answer)
```

Comment: for this part 're.match(regex, string).group()' i get an error for regex, that it is not defined

Comment: The regex should be `r"\d+"`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to just check where the string begins.

```
str_ = "..."
if not str_[2].isdigit():
    # basic
elif not str_[5].isdigit():
    # complex
```

Assuming that your strings always have 2 or 5 digits at the start, which seems to be the case based on your question.

Comment: thanks for your help. it is working but I have other types of strings too but if i first divide them to a group then it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Use a character group to catch all digits 0 to 9, and then use curly brackets to specify occurrences.

E.g.

```
[0-9]{3}
```

would catch 3 digits.